# How do I improve my ability to get loans to use as leverage for my business?

Tags: loans, credit-score, small-business, european-union

*Relating to Europe, but an US-focused answer is also welcome.*

Plan:

I have a small stain on my credit history due to a tax issue. I am otherwise financially sound.

I am not big enough for a bank to give me loans for certain things. I had recently took a loan out to purchase a bulk of products that I later re-sold. The type of loan was "personal" and I only specified it was for personal needs. It was for 3 months and I paid it in 3 months.

I didn't need the loan; I simply wanted to see if the bank would approve a small-medium sized loan to me. The deal worked for me better because of the smaller risk posed by 3 payments instead of a bigger one.

After it was all done, it occurred to me that this could be used to boost my financial reputation in terms of someone who'd need a loan / credit later on.

Assume the numbers:

I take a **loan for $10,000 for 12 months.**

I'd have to pay $1,100 monthly for these 12 months. **Instead, because I'm well off and just needed this to lessen my personal risk, I pay it all off in 3 months.**

In my humble opinion, I just hopefully traded $1,100 now for trust and a bigger leverage in the future.

Does paying off such loans earlier than anticipated improve the metrics the bank would use to evaluate me for future loans?

As such, do these actions of paying upfront, paying full upfront help me in any way or measure to raise my trust within the system?

My end goal is to have the ability to take out larger or longer term loans in the future.

Comment: Can you reduce your question? The title is asking about credit, but the content of the question has a number of details on lending, leverage, and specific dollar amounts. Money.SE tries to focus questions on one specific, answerable question. I'll think about this on my break and see if I can suggest some edits.

Comment: @Freiheit Looking at it, you're right. My intentions [are] is the question. Really, what I'm asking is "How can I get better leverage for future, bigger loans?" with a lot of details on my plan in-between. I knew of some other ways but I was asking specifically about this. -- Any edits would be appreciated!

Comment: Making financial transactions purely for the sale of improving your credit score is a waste of time. Your credit score isn't that important. Gaming the system isn't going to have a meaningful impact on it.

Comment: @GlenPierce I am neutral on gaming the system. I was trying to see if this is a point of view that can have some meaning.

Comment: Your credit score goes up from activities besides taking on debt. Cell phones, internet services, utility bills, and more all contribute to your credit score.

Comment: Why not invest the money you´d spend in interest and closing-costs to build your assets. Having assets does not cost you, and they can also be leveraged.

Comment: @Daniel I believe my fortune as of now is not exactly as huge, but I can afford to see what works and what doesn't. I'm currently learning what the possibilities are. My assets that aren't currently generating anything are 2 apartments, a car, which in my country amount to ~$250k and about $70-80k cash. I'm, at best economically illiterate but I have common sense, this was an experiment with small sums in order to learn about bulk purchasing, sourcing and many others. I chose to learn about the entire production pipeline of a product instead of gambling on stocks. Just trying out small things.

Comment: The point is, you are more likely to get loaned $250k because you already have $250k as security than because you have loaned and paid back such sum in the past. I don´t see how spending your money on unnecessary interest would put you in a better position that building further assets with it ...

Comment: Your lack of financial knowledge is a bit appalling.  There was less risk with borrowed money?  Not true.  There is less risk if you can pay cash for inventory to be resold.  With that kind of understanding it is best to seek knowledge rather than another loan.

Comment: @PeteB. I think this doesn't help the community to continue the discussion: `seek knowledge`. Well, here I am.

Comment: I've marked as a duplicate given that there is nothing too special here different from the generic case. Getting a loan for a small business is not too different from getting a personal loan, since you will likely need to personally guarantee the loan anyway, meaning it is your personal credit rating that matters.

Comment: I'd focus on the question of why you can't get a *business* loan for *business* expenses, rather than continually taking out personal loans.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Very little of your score is based on closed accounts. And having a lot of relatively new accounts lowers your Average Age of Accounts (AAoA) and pulls your scores down. The best way to pull your scores up is to have 3 credit cards, and one open loan. Keep a small balance reported on one card only. That formula will maximize your scores.

This is based on the FICO scoring method, in the US. I have no idea what is used in Europe.

Comment: Great. Can you please give me more reading material on this?

Comment: I can direct you to a site that is owned by Fair Isaac, the company that produces the FICO scoring algorithms - again I have no idea what is used in Europe.

Have look around www.MyFICO.com

Comment: Coming back: undervalued answer. Understanding FICO and its metrics can, indeed, give you some good answers. It seems the biggest factor in your reputation is having a credit that you keep paying and this has to keep going for quite a few years, this way, the bank knows you're serious but your income also has to be adjusted for another loan, e.g: be able to pay it back to back with the old loan.